# How to disable mailman configuration for User who subscribed mailing list?

Tags: plesk, mailman

I'm using Plesk and don't want User change their setting in Mailman, do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Switch off "Enable mailing lists" setting on subscription or on hosting plan.